# iptables: Access from local machine to docker container is not possible

Tags: docker, webserver, iptables

I have an issue in regards to my iptables setup. My goal is to reach the https based webserver inside a docker container from the server machine itself.

The setup is the following:
[image]

- The server is connected to the internet via eth0 and serves http via port 443.
- Any users from the outside (internet) reach the server via the ip address 1.2.3.4.
- It is connected to the internal network via eth1 and serves dhcp, dns and some more services.
- Any users from the inside (intranet) reach the server via the ip address 10.0.0.1.
- The docker container is connected via docker1 on the server. The later has the ip address 10.8.0.2 inside the docker network.
- The docker container serves the webserver on port 1443, but iptables forwards (NAT) requests on port 443 to its address 10.8.0.1 and the destination port 1443.

What is working:

- The webserver is perfectly reachable from the internet and the intranet.
- The webserver can be reached from the server itself using the address 10.8.0.1:1443.

What is not working:

- Any client which is working directly on the server can not reach the docker webserver using https://example.com:443. Using https://10.8.0.1:8443 would work, but fails due to a certificate error. It is not a goal to skip the certificate check as a workaround.

Excerpt of the iptable configuration:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i docker1 -o docker1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.1:1443
iptables -A FORWARD -o docker1 -p tcp --dport 1443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i docker1 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i docker1 -j DROP
```

Due to that "complicated" setup I am no longer able to understand which of the iptable rules and chains need to be applied to make this work so I am seeking for your help to solve that issue.

Brainstorming about the issue using a simplified model and my understanding of the iptable chains the way of the packages might/should look like this:

1. Origin is a local application (wget).
2. The packages go through the OUTPUT table.
3. The packages go through the POSTROUTING table.
4. Magic happens...
5. The packages arrive again in the PREROUTING table.
6. The packages might go trough INPUT again.
7. The packages might arrive at the target application (webserver).